# Estructuración de una tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql

¡Hola a todos!

Mi publicación va en relación a una asesoría. Resulta que estoy estructurando una base de datos, tengo una tabla **(persona)** al cual le pueden aplicar o no ciertas **características**. Por ejemplo, si le gusta las **artesanías**, se le habilitará un formulario para pedir algunos campos; si le gusta la **cocina**, se le pedirán otros campos, y así sucesivamente.

Para simplificar, quiero crear una única tabla llamada **preferencias**, donde estén todos estos campos. Por normalización diría que lo mejor es crear una tabla para cada característica de información a la que podría aplicar o no una persona, pero luego pienso en la cantidad de índices y join que habría que crear para una consulta, entonces no sé que sería lo mejor.

¿Ustedes en su experiencia, que me recomiendan?

Gracias.

Comment: Preguntas basadas en recomendaciones terminan cerradas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal seria que crearas las tablas de modo que te queden lo mas normalizadas posibles por integridad de informacion.
En ese caso yo crearia una tabla de caracteristicas, y una tabla de campos, y crearia una tabla intermedia entre ambas tablas, por si llegasen a haber campos repetidos entre caracteristicas y asi solo se asocian las caracteristicas y los campos que se deban asociar en la tabla intermedia y no tendras redundancia de informacion, que al final la base de datos su objetivo es no tener informacion redundante ni repetida.

Answer (score 1):

Pues uno de los principios de las bases de datos es la integridad de la información (información que no debe ser redundante). Quizá una persona pueda tener preferencias, y las preferencias tienen ciertas características similares, por lo que hay que crear una tabla intermedia...igual el proceso de normalización te dará la respuesta... De igual manera piensa a futuro cuando creas una BD..

Comment: Considera no responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues estas terminan cerradas